# Judging Length of SQL Query based on Explain

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, explain

I am trying to get a ball park estimate about how long a query is going to take based on the output of the explain. I am using a MYSQL database.

I know that you can't determine how a long a query is going to take with any certainty.  I am just looking for a ballpark estimate, i.e. 1 hour, 8 hours, 1 day, 2 weeks etc.  Thank you!

[image]

Comment: This is going to be guesswork, really, but if you'd like to hear some estimates, can you show us the query, the table structure (indexes and number of rows), and tell us a bit about your hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't, it totally depends of your infrastructure. The explain plan is first of all really indicative, and then really relative to your server.

Use TKPROF for better results anyway.

EDIT: Mysql doesn't have tkprof unlike Oracle (The rest is still valid) Instead, use PROFILING for mor relevant informations: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html

Comment: Like I said, I am just looking for a ballpark. Is the equivalent to a similar query that transverses four million rows, since the rows=1mil*4*1?

Comment: Yeah, .. what about the 2nd join with table b?

Comment: I am a novice when it comes to interpreting the explain, so I am guess I am asking what it is even saying when with table b it requires 4 rows?

Comment: you're right I watched the key_len column. Well you also have to know how many columns you're selecting, (is ALL standing for * ?), because it could generate a consequent overhead